# use a string character-location identity to create a new variable

Tags: r, string, if-statement

So I have been able to achieve my desired output, but I am sure that one can use a `string` to achieve a much more efficient code.

Let play with this data

```
set.seed(123)

A <- 1:100
type.a <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1433)
type.b <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1425)
type.c <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1125)
type.d <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1233)

df1 <- data.frame(A, type.a, type.b, type.c, type.d)
```

Now we want to create a new variable for `df1` that will identity if a `type(a:d)` begun with number 1. So I have used this code:

```
df1$Type_1 <- with(df1, ifelse((type.a < 2000 & type.a > 999)|(type.b < 2000 & type.c > 999)|
                                (type.c < 2000 & type.c > 999)|(type.d < 2000 & type.d > 999), 1,0))
```

Or similiarly, this also:

```
df1$type_1 <- with(df1, ifelse(type.a < 2000 & type.a > 999, 1,
                              ifelse(type.b < 2000 & type.c > 999, 1, 
                                     ifelse(type.c < 2000 & type.c > 999, 1,
                                             ifelse(type.d < 2000 & type.d > 999, 1,0)))))
```

**Now my question form two parts**

How can you use a `string` which will look at **only the first digit** of `type(a:d)` to test if it is equal to our constraint. *(in this instance equal to 1)*

Secondly, I have more than four columns of data. Thus I dont think it is efficient I specify column names each time. Can the use of `[,x:y]` be used?

The code then be used to create 9 new columns of data (*ie. type_1 & type_2 ... type_9*), as the **first digit** of our `type(a:d)` has a range of 1:9

Comment: How about just `df1$Type_1 <- rowSums((df1 < 2000) & (df1 > 999))` instead of that huge and unnecessary `ifelse` statement? (Or `+(!!rowSums((df1 < 2000) & (df1 > 999)))` if you have several column matching condition within the same row)

Comment: I have never used it that is all. I want a string that equal 0 when the TRUE/FALSE vectors all equal FALSE, and a 1 when the TRUE/FALSE has at least one TRUE

Comment: You can wrap with `any` i.e. `lapply(yourdf[-1], function(x) +(any(substr(x, 1, 1)==1)))`

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the help, I have more of an understanding of substr now, thanks. Can you submit as a solution with the column names specified than we can close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substr` to extract the first character of a string.  As there are four columns that start with `type`, we can use `grep` to get the numeric index of columns, we loop the columns with `lapply`, check whether the 1st character is equal to 1.  If we want to know whether there is at least one value that meets the condition, we can wrap it with `any`.  Using `lapply` returns a `list` output with a length of 1 for each `list` element.  As we need a binary (0/1) instead of logical (FALSE/TRUE), we can wrap with `+` to coerce the logical to binary representation.

```
 indx <- grep('^type', colnames(df1))
 lapply(df1[indx], function(x) +(any(substr(x, 1, 1)==1)))
```

If we need a vector output

```
 vapply(df1[indx], function(x) +(any(substr(x, 1, 1)==1)), 1L)
```

Comment: Just a question with the `lapply` solution you offered. It searches along the columns for the  number `1`. But I want to search across rows to find if the number `1` appears. How can you adjust for this?

Comment: Try `+(!!rowSums('dim<-'(substring(as.matrix(df1[indx]), 1, 1)==1, dim(df1[indx]))))`

Answer (score 1):

Great and elegant answer by @akrun. I was interested in the 2nd part of your question. Specifically about how you're going to use the first part to create the new 9 columns you mention. I don't know if I'm missing something, but instead of checking each time if the first element matches 1,2,3, etc. you can just simply capture that first element. Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


set.seed(123)

A <- 1:100
type.a <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1433)
type.b <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1425)
type.c <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1125)
type.d <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1233)

df1 <- data.frame(A, type.a, type.b, type.c, type.d)


   df1 %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(substr(.,1,1))) %>%                     # keep first digit
  ungroup %>%
  gather(variable, type, -A) %>%                           # create combinations of rows and digits
  select(-variable) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0("type_",type),
         value = 1) %>%
  group_by(A,type) %>%                                     
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%                        # count how many times the row belongs to each type
  ungroup %>%
  spread(type, value, fill=0) %>%                          # create the new columns
  inner_join(df1, by="A") %>%                              # join back initial info
  select(A, starts_with("type."), starts_with("type_"))    # order columns


#     A   type.a   type.b   type.c   type.d type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5 type_6 type_7 type_8 type_9
# 1   1 4196.838 3987.671 7473.662 4118.106      0      0      1      2      0      0      1      0      0
# 2   2 4670.156 5366.059 6476.465 4071.935      0      0      0      2      1      1      0      0      0
# 3   3 7233.629 4648.464 4701.712 3842.782      0      0      1      2      0      0      1      0      0
# 4   4 5101.039 4504.752 5611.093 3702.251      0      0      1      1      2      0      0      0      0
# 5   5 5185.269 3643.944 4533.868 4460.982      0      0      1      2      1      0      0      0      0
# 6   6 7457.688 4935.835 4464.222 5408.344      0      0      0      2      1      0      1      0      0
# 7   7 5660.493 3881.511 4112.822 2516.478      0      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
# 8   8 3187.167 2623.183 4331.056 5261.372      0      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
# 9   9 4015.740 4458.177 6857.271 6524.820      0      0      0      2      0      2      0      0      0
# 10 10 4361.366 6309.570 4939.218 7512.329      0      0      0      2      0      1      1      0      0
# .. ..      ...      ...      ...      ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
```

Example when we have column A and B in the beginning:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


    set.seed(123)

    A <- 1:100
    B <- 101:200
    type.a <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1433)
    type.b <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1425)
    type.c <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1125)
    type.d <- rnorm(100, mean=5000, sd=1233)

    df1 <- data.frame(A,B, type.a, type.b, type.c, type.d)


    # work by grouping on A and B
df1 %>% 
  group_by(A,B) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(substr(.,1,1))) %>%                
  ungroup %>%
  gather(variable, type, -c(A,B)) %>%                     
  select(-variable) %>%
  mutate(type = paste0("type_",type),
         value = 1) %>%
  group_by(A,B,type) %>%                                     
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  spread(type, value, fill=0) %>%                       
  inner_join(df1, by=c("A","B")) %>%                            
  select(A,B, starts_with("type."), starts_with("type_"))  


#     A   B   type.a   type.b   type.c   type.d type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5 type_6 type_7 type_8 type_9
# 1   1 101 4196.838 3987.671 7473.662 4118.106      0      0      1      2      0      0      1      0      0
# 2   2 102 4670.156 5366.059 6476.465 4071.935      0      0      0      2      1      1      0      0      0
# 3   3 103 7233.629 4648.464 4701.712 3842.782      0      0      1      2      0      0      1      0      0
# 4   4 104 5101.039 4504.752 5611.093 3702.251      0      0      1      1      2      0      0      0      0
# 5   5 105 5185.269 3643.944 4533.868 4460.982      0      0      1      2      1      0      0      0      0
# 6   6 106 7457.688 4935.835 4464.222 5408.344      0      0      0      2      1      0      1      0      0
# 7   7 107 5660.493 3881.511 4112.822 2516.478      0      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
# 8   8 108 3187.167 2623.183 4331.056 5261.372      0      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
# 9   9 109 4015.740 4458.177 6857.271 6524.820      0      0      0      2      0      2      0      0      0
# 10 10 110 4361.366 6309.570 4939.218 7512.329      0      0      0      2      0      1      1      0      0
# .. .. ...      ...      ...      ...      ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
```

However, in this case you should notice that you have one A value for each line. So, B isn't really needed in order to define your rows (in a unique way). Therefore, you can work exactly as before (when B wasn't there) and just join B to your result:

```
df1 %>% 
      select(-B) %>%
      group_by(A) %>% 
      mutate_each(funs(substr(.,1,1))) %>%                 
      ungroup %>%
      gather(variable, type, -A) %>%                        
      select(-variable) %>%
      mutate(type = paste0("type_",type),
             value = 1) %>%
      group_by(A,type) %>%                                     
      summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%            # count how many times the row belongs to each type
      ungroup %>%
      spread(type, value, fill=0) %>%                          
      inner_join(df1, by="A") %>%                              
      mutate(B=B) %>%
      select(A,B, starts_with("type."), starts_with("type_"))
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for offering the solution, but can you adjust the code so that the original df1 with 5 variables are retained, but then we introduce our new variables type_1:type_9 and that is the row sum of the  numbers that begin with type_x

Comment: Super Stuff, one more point. Lets say, we have `B <- 101:200` and thus `df1 <- data.frame(A, B, Type.a, Type.b, Type.c, Type.d)`. Can you adjust the code so that `B` is also included in the output

Comment: B is another column next to A, so I think you are interested in pairs {A,B}, right? You'll probably just need to group by A and B at the same time, but I'll check and update the answer.

Comment: I have more than 2 columns (more than A and B) but I just need to see an example to understand your code to see how we can include more than the one variable

Comment: The "group by", in any language, works if you pass it a unique row identifier. A set of columns that define each row you want to create. Your objective is to work by row, so it will break if you pass it columns that create duplicates. It will work better if you work using column A and then you join back column B (or any other columns) to the results table. I will update soon.

Comment: Ok, so I understand, that if variable is not unique, I can just include it in the `select`command. One problem with your code, I notice that there in each `type_1`a value of 1 is assigned. I am not sure why and this is not what I want. A value should be assigned here if the `type.x` begins with the number 1. So in fact the first row should have a count of 2 in `type_4` - as we have two occurences of a number beginning with 4. Then a count of 1 in `type_3` and `type_7`. Do you get me?

Comment: That's due to the command "distinct()" I included. It focuses on spotting if the row belongs to each type.x (1/0 means yes/no). I'll update to count how many times it is included.

Comment: One thing I noticed, with the third code that `groups_by(A)` and `mutate(B=B)` with `select(A,B...)` is that it unneccarisly puts a value of 1 into the `type_1` even though `distinct` is not used. Can you adjust the third code, so the results with the second are the same. Thanks

Comment: I think it is now searching through the second column B, which I dont want

Comment: Yes, you're right. I said we have to ignore column B, but I didn't do it. I just need to ignore it before I group by A. It's updated now.